# Sharepoint powershell cmdlets with Node/SPFX

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, spfx, sharepoint-rest-api, sharepointframework

I'm administering a Sharepoint Online site right now. Is there a way to run Sharepoint powershell cmdlets externally from SPFX/ NodeJS. I'm trying to create a UI for disabling versioning for a document library. Seems that disabling versioning could only be achieved through powershell right now.

(Or is there an sharepoint api endpoint for actually doing it, not sure)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot run powershell cmdlets from SPFx. SPFx is a framework to build applications that run in a browser.

But you can use REST API (the easiest way to use it is probably [pnpjs](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/lists/) to wrap it). You could try something like this (just update the library property):

```js
await sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Documents").update({ EnableVersioning: false });
```